# linux/solaris + verify duplicate valid IP address from file

Tags: shell-script, sed, awk, perl, ksh

what the best way to find duplicate IP from file ( I have ksh script in this script I need to write function that check for duplicate IP )

for example if IP - 192.1926.23.52  exists twice in file - config_IP.txt
then need to print "duplicate IP - xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx"

- solution can be with ksh or perl one liner , sed ,awk etc

the format of the file should be as the following:

more config_IP.txt

```
 # NETWORK adminstration


 192.192.23.150 192.192.23.120
 192.192.23.152 192.192.23.52      
 192.192.23.153 192.192.23.53      
 192.192.23.154 192.192.23.54      


 #NETWORK private

 192.192.23.170  192.192.23.122         
 192.192.23.172  192.192.23.126  
 192.192.23.174  192.192.23.123     
 192.192.23.177  192.192.23.121  



# NETWORK oracle internal


152.3.4.12 152.3.4.12 
152.3.4.14 152.3.4.16 


# NETWORK oracle ext

152.3.4.10 152.3.4.19
```

Comment: What is the expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this (Assuming you want to check for IP against the entire file, not just against the one present in the same line):

```
awk '/^[0-9]/{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)if(a[$i]++==1) print "Duplicate IP : ",$i;}' file
```

Comment: Not find duplicate IP try - this - echo "10.106.23.177 10.106.23.121" > file echo "10.106.23.177 1.1.1.1" >> file awk '/^[0-9 \.]+$/{ if(a[$0]++) print "Duplicate IP : ",$0;}' RS=" " file

Comment: updated the solution..

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure I understand the question correctly, but if you want to find duplicate IPs in a file like the one above, just put one IP per line then run it through `sort` and then `uniq -c` which will report the count of identical lines before each one:

```bsh
cat config_IP.txt | sed "s/\s\s*/\n/g" | sort | uniq -c
```

If you want to check another IPs against the file, you can just group it with the `cat`:

```bsh
( cat config_IP.txt; echo "12.34.56.78 90.101.121.131" ) \
    | sed "s/\s\s*/\n/g" | sort | uniq -c
```

You might also want to add some `grep` to filter out lines not containing IP addresses before you start sorting.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
cat config_IP.txt|egrep -v '^#|^$'|awk '{if($1==$2){print "Duplicate IP - "$1}}'
```

Comment: isnt find duplicate IP , please try this echo "10.106.23.177 10.106.23.121 10.106.23.177 1.1.1.1" > file ,                cat file |egrep -v '^#|^$'|awk '{if($1==$2){print "Duplicate IP - "$1}}'